# user id and username not inserting with relationship

Tags: php, laravel

```
class Country extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Post::class,UserProfile::class,'country_id','user_id','id','user_id');
    }
}
```

This is Country Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    // protected $table = 'user';

    protected $primaryKey = 'username';

    protected $keyType = 'string';

    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * The name of the "created at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';

    /**
     * The name of the "updated at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token','email'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */ 
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    // public static function boot(){
    //     parent::boot();
    //     static::addGlobalScope('vfu',function(Builder $builder){
    //         return $builder->where('email_verified_at',"<>",null);

    //     });

        // public static function boot()
        // {
        //     parent::boot();
        //     static::addGlobalScope(new VerifiedUsers);

        // static::addGlobalScope(new NotVerifiedUsers);

        // static::addGlobalScope('nvfu',function(Builder $builder){
        //     return $builder->where('email_verified_at','=',null);

        //  // App\User::withoutGlobalScope('nvfu')->get();
        // });
    public function scopeVfu($query){
        return $query->where('email_verified_at','<>',null);

    }
    public function scopeNvfu($query){
        return $query->where('email_verified_at','=',null);

    }
    public function scopeFindById($query,$id)
    {
        return $query->where('id',$id);
    }
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class,'user_id','id');
    }
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class,'user_id','id');
    }
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'role_user','user_id','role_id','id','id');
    }
    public function history()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserHistory::class,'user_id','id');
    }
}
```

This is User Model

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $users = \App\User::with(['roles','profile'])->get();
        return view('dashboard.users.index',compact('users'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        $roles = \App\Role::all();
        $countries = \App\Country::all();
        return view('dashboard.users.create',compact('countries','roles'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $user = [
            'username' => $request->username,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
        ];
        $user = \App\User::create($user);
               $filename = sprintf('thumbnail_%s.jpg',random_int(1, 1000));
        if ($request->hasFile('photo')) 
         $filename = $request->file('photo')->storeAs('profiles',$filename,'public');
     else
        $filename = "profiles/dummy.jpg";
    if ($user) {
        $profile = new \App\UserProfile([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'city' => $request->city,
            'country_id' => $request->country,
            'photo' => $filename,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
        ]);
        $user->profile()->save($profile);
        $user->roles()->attach($request->roles);
        return redirect()->route('users.index');
    }

}
```

This is Controller

```
class UserProfile extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
    }
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class,'country_id','id');
    }
}
```

This is UserProfile Model

```
@extends('dashboard.layout')
@section('content')
<form action="{{route('users.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-row align-item-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="inputUsername"> Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" name="username" id="inputUsername" placeholder="UserName">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="inputName">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control mb-2" id="inputName" placeholder="Full Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="inputUserEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control mb-2" name="email" id="inputUserEmail" placeholder="Enter a valid Email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control mb-2" id="inputPassword" placeholder="************">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="inputPhone">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control mb-2" id="inputPhone" placeholder="+923132244567">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="selectCountry">Select Country</label>
            <select name="country" id="" class="form-control">
                @if(!$countries->isEmpty())
                @foreach($countries as $country)
                <option value="{{$country->id}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
                @endif
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
            <label for="inputCity">City</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control mb-2" id="inputCity" placeholder="Enter Your City Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="selectRoles">Select Roles</label>
            <select name="roles[]" id="selectRoles" class="form-control" multiple>
                @if(!$roles->isEmpty())
                @foreach($roles as $role)
                <option value="{{$role->id}}">{{$role->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
                @endif
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 my-3">
            <label for="inputFileName">Profile Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="photo" class="form-custom-control mb-2" id="inputFileName">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Add New User</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
@endsection
```

This is create view

I have used this code with relationships when i create user and getting this error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `user_profiles` (`user_id`, `city`, `country_id`, `photo`, `phone`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, Karachi, 1, profiles/thumbnail_385.jpg, +923148790984, 2020-02-20 04:49:17, 2020-02-20 04:49:17))

Answer (score 3):

Your `User` model has:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];
```

Then your controller does:

```
$user = [
    'username' => $request->username,
    'name' => $request->name,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
];
$user = \App\User::create($user);
```

This will fail, as `username` is not mass-assignable.  As the docs describe, [the `create()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) will only accept fields you have explicitly whitelisted in `$fillable`.

For this to work, you need to add `username` to the list of fillable fields:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'username', 'name', 'email', 'password',
];
```

**Side note:** The test/error handling you have set up to make sure a user is created before trying to create a profile is not working.  The reason is that you first set `$user` as an array - the `create()` fails, but `$user` is still an array.  So your test:

```
if ($user) {
    // $user is an array so this still works
    // create user profile
}
```

still evaluates as `TRUE`.  Maybe better would be to set up the user array with a different variable name, eg:

```
$array = [ ... user values ... ];
$user = \App\User::create($array);
```

Or even simpler do it all in one command:

```
$user = \App\User::create([
    // ... user values ...
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $filename = sprintf('thumbnail_%s.jpg', random_int(1, 1000));

        if ($request->hasFile('photo'))
            $filename = $request->file('photo')->storeAs('profiles', $filename, 'public');
        else
            $filename = "profiles/dummy.jpg";

        $user = \App\User::create([
            'username' => $request->username,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
        ])->profile()->create([
            'city' => $request->city,
            'country_id' => $request->country,
            'photo' => $filename,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
        ]);

        if ($user) {
            $user->roles()->attach($request->roles);
            return redirect()->route('users.index');
        } else {
            //redirect to error page
        }
    }
```

Comment: Passing user ID is not needed as we're creating a related model directly while crated a  main model. Eloquent will know to automatically pass the user_id based on your model relationship declaration

Comment: But user ID is not inserting